# Using Row Level Security to protect the table that tracks row level securities

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, row-level-security

The general setup of my RLS is that I have a table like Orders:

```
OrderID  Customer
1        John
2        Bill
```

And a table, RowLevelSecurityPermissions, that tracks which principal is allowed to see which order:

```
Principal  Table   ID
admin      Orders  -1              --can see everything
sales1     Orders  1               --can only see order 1
sales2     Orders  2               --can only see order 2
```

RLS functions look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sec.OrdersRLSFilter(@OrderId AS int) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN 

    SELECT 1 AS R
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT null 
        FROM sec.RowLevelSecurityPermissions 
        WHERE Username = USER_NAME() AND TableName = 'Orders' AND Id IN (-1, @OrderId)
    )


CREATE SECURITY POLICY OrdersSecurityPolicy
ADD FILTER PREDICATE sec.OrdersRLSFilter(OrderId)
ON dbo.Orders
WITH (STATE = ON);
```

I also wanted to protect the RowLevelSecurityPermissions table in the same way so any principal doing a `select *` from it would only see their own rows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sec.RowLevelSecurityPermissionsRLSFilter(@Principal AS VARCHAR) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 

    RETURN SELECT 1 AS R WHERE USER_NAME() IN ('admin', @Principal)

CREATE SECURITY POLICY RowLevelSecurityPermissionsSecurityPolicy
ADD FILTER PREDICATE sec.RowLevelSecurityPermissionsRLSFilter(Principal)
ON sec.RowLevelSecurityPermissions
WITH (STATE = ON);
```

I thought this would be the effective equivalent of

```
select * from sec.RowLevelSecurityPermissions WHERE USER_NAME() IN ('admin', Principal)
```

which (as a query) does work if logged in as sales1; it shows me only sales1's rows (and if logged in as admin it shows me all)

However, when I go the RLS approach and do a `SELECT * FROM sec.RowLevelSecurityPermissions` I get no rows if logged in as sales1; where did my logic break down?

Comment: `(@Principal AS VARCHAR)<—`@Principal == varchar(1)

Comment: In addition: server principals and database principals are of type `SYSNAME` which is a synonym for `NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL`. Using `VARCHAR` of any length will break for logins with international characters. Yes, those are things.

Comment: Note also that `USER_NAME` returns the actual username in the case of a Windows user loggedin via an AD group. If you want the group name you need to use `SUSER_SNAME`. And as a side point: RLS is not a complete security framework, as it can be relatively easily circumvented using custom queries.

Answer (score 0):

To protect the RowLevelSecurityPermissions table with same way try following query.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_RLSfilter(@Principal as Varchar(100))
    RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    Return SELECT 1 AS result Where DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID() = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(@Principal)
Go

CREATE SECURITY POLICY dbo.RLSfilters
ADD FILTER PREDICATE dbo.fn_RLSfilter(Principal)
ON dbo.RowLevelSecurityPermissions
WITH(STATE = ON)
```

***Output***

[image]